# ordering results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having trouble with an SQL ORDER function.  My product database has images and prices. What I want is to order my results like this is: All products that have an image displayed by their price from low to high, then have my products without images displayed by their price from low to high.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here is my table structure:

```
id - brand - code - name - type - pile_weight - size - pcs_ctn - sf_ctn - lbs_ctn - picture - description - color_code - manufacturer - supplier - pricing_unit - total_wgt - retail_price - sale_price - dealer_price - featured
```

Here is what I have done as far as the query goes:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY picture, retail_price
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY picture DESC, retail_price ASC
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY CASE WHEN picture = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, picture, retail_price ASC
```

Comment: Please add your current query, and demonstrate that you have attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: To get an answer you should at least describe your tables structure

Comment: Try to add ORDER BY img_column, price_column Where img_column

Comment: `order by img = '' desc, price asc`

Answer (score 1):

You should mention your table design clearly. Still I am posting your solution this sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb8f7/2

```
select * from table1 order by ifnull(image,0) ,price asc
```